# Modify the Commit Message of a Pushed Commit. (Mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, commit, bitbucket

I created a dummy repository on bitbucket to try to learn how to do this. I've seen this done in Git, but I am unsure if this is possible in Hg.

I have the following hg log:

```
changeset:   3:742dd9f71f46
tag:         tip
user:        RHsu
date:        Tue Apr 09 09:58:55 2013 -0400
summary:     added some text to 3

changeset:   2:dd431695edcd
user:        RHsu
date:        Tue Apr 09 09:58:30 2013 -0400
summary:     Let's try to amend this commit

changeset:   1:b59ed9c945f9
user:        RHsu
date:        Tue Apr 09 09:58:15 2013 -0400
summary:     added some text to t1

changeset:   0:a8a24f3831ab
user:        RHsu
date:        Tue Apr 09 09:52:32 2013 -0400
summary:     Add text files for testing
```

These changesets have been pushed  to bitbucket. How can I ammend the commit message of changeset2?

EDIT: I have tried using `histedit`, but that only changes local commits. Then when I push, two heads are created.

EDIT: Different from the other question since this question deals with editing a commit that has been pushed onto bitbucket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org/) has a strip function that can be use to strip a changeset from the repository. That's what you have to use in order to get rid of the head you don't want. You get to it at `https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/admin/strip`. You can also click on the little gear icon when looking at your repo on the web page and then it will show you the admin interface which has a section for stripping changesets.

Comment: That appears to remove the changeset rather than modify the commit message.

Comment: @Rhs: In git what you are doing is creating a new changeset with a new commit message and telling it to forget the old one is there. So it's basically equivalent. You can tell this is what happens because your changeset has a new hash after you push the commit message.

Comment: Something to look forward to; future versions of Mercurial will support the Changeset Evolution feature, which will automatically propagate the “forgetting” of the old changeset if you amend it.